# SignalR javascript callback not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I have hub class:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    // Send message
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.addMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " " + message);
    }
}
```

And javascript:

```
// Proxy created on the fly
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

// Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
chat.addMessage = function(message) {
    alert("message:" + message);
    $('#chat').append('<div>' + message + '</div>');
};


$("#sendButton").click(function () {

    // Call the chat method on the server
    chat.send($('#message').val())
        .done(function () {
            console.log('Success!')
        })
        .fail(function (e) {
            console.warn(e);
        })
});

// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start();
```

All conection are fine:
[image]

If I use breakpoint in here **Clients.addMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " " + message);** everything is fine.

**But i don't get callback on javascript function.**
**alert("message:" + message);** never executes

Comment: The code looks fine. Where are you running it? IIS? VS?

Comment: Is the javascript code above in the ready event or similar?

Comment: @escouser Yes it is, and if I check in fidller2 the traffic, there is no traffic sended after calling Clients.addMessage(...);

Comment: @JinDave - were you able to make this work? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @DhwanilShah No but in close time I will try it again, and I report here my result

Comment: @JinDave - I was able to get it to work. I had the SignalR stuff working correctly - but the client side jQuery I wrote for updating the UI was not correct. I fixed that, and it started to work like a charm. I am amazed by the simplicity and power of SignalR. This could allow for some very interesting applications.

Comment: @DavidHorák - did this ever get resolved?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have multiple hubs configured on the server and only one of them is getting called-back.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the client side Signalr hub?

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```